# Comparative view in Paraview with identical Pipeline

Tags: pipeline, paraview

I am visualizing multiple steps of a simulation and exporting them as a movie. Since the geometry is complicated, I would like to show it from several perspectives side-by-side, with the same pipeline.

Paraview has "Render View (Comparative)" which lets me do just that, but it resets the pipeline for each new comparative view. Since the pipeline is complex, I have to set it up manually for each new view, which is tedious, and changes to one don't change the other.

Am I overlooking a simple way to just show exactly the same thing, just from different point, in the comparative render view?

Comment: Which version are you using? I don't remember having the comparative view resetting the pipeline...

Comment: The latest stable 4.3.1.

Comment: I'm also using that one but I don't understand your setting.. The comparative view is, for example, to see the same data at with the same camera at different timesteps (or showing different blocks, or at different parameters of a filter in the pipeline). Do you mean that it resets the visibility of the elements in the pipeline?

Comment: @lib: yes. I'd like to use it to see the same thing, just from a different angle. I see it is meant for something different, but is there something that just is a different view?

Comment: Hi @eudoxos !

Have you found a solution to this problem?

I am in the same page as you but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a new view in the same layout (http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Beginning_GUI#Split_windows) , and when you make a video you will record both because they are in the same layout. 
Still, they will not be synchronized (to change the visibility of an object, you will have to do it in each view), maybe for automating this the python tracing can help.